# using outcome of clustering as an ordinal scale for regression - feasible?

Tags: clustering, ordinal-data, nonlinear-regression

Suppose I have access to five dental surgeries, who volunteered to collect data about patients and their regular check-ups. The dental surgeries are quite up to completely different from each other (size, sociodemographics of patients etc.). The collection of data for each patient runs as a small questionnaire (14 items on medical and sociodemographic preconditions). I want to identify, what has an influence on how long (= how many minutes) the patient needs for the check-up and potential ad-hoc therapy in need.
There is *no* reason to assume, that this duration in minutes is normally distributed, not even for the single dental surgery.

Does the following idea hold - or is there a more direct way to work through?

1) I apply partitional clustering for each of the dental surgeries, but only on the duration of check-up plus therapy. I.e. I get one-dimensional values (in minutes), which I join to N groups (N a predefined number, e.g. 5) in such a way, that the mean of each group is as far away as possible from the means of the other groups.

2) Step 1) has established an ordinal scale for each dental surgery. I have heeps of data. Now I can start an ordinal regression...

2a) for each dental surgery separately
2b) for all dental surgeries together (?)

My main questions are: is 1)+2) as establishing a scale of one's own feasible? Are there (easier, more correct) alternatives? One alternative I could imagine are quintiles instead of 1).

Statos

Comment: What makes you to consider your time scale after the clustering ordinal? It is discrete. A discrete scale can be nonetheless interval.

Comment: Not quite sure why you need to make a scale in the first place.

Comment: Time scale after clustering: I'd picture it not a time scale anymore, but rather a "being a more/less complicated at the dentist's.

Comment: The main reason for not just using time directly is 2 b), the inter-surgery research. Time itself would heavily vary accross surgeries and normalisation is not possible because of lacking normality assumption.

Comment: Typically you'd deal with that by putting predictors representing surgeries into the model. If you're proposing this scale because of perceived difficulties with using duration as a response variable in a regression you might want to make sure they're insuperable: you're going to (1) throw away some information about the thing you say you're interested in, & (2) have a model very difficult to re-interpret in terms of that. There are many ways of modelling non-normal responses. And do note that the errors may be (approximately) normal though the response isn't.

Comment: Note also that the relationship of the variance to the expected response is something to check. In no particular order, & not exclusively, some things to consider might be: (1) transforming the response, (2) using robust standard error estimates, (3) making more appropriate distributional assumptions (e.g. gamma) & modelling accordingly, & (4) fitting a general linear model & checking your assumptions to see which, if any, are discredited.

Comment: I will add dummy variables for the surgeries and work through the usual regression workflow. Thanks, Scortchi!

Comment: You're welcome. And don't forget to consider including interactions of those dummy variables with the others.  And, depending on the purposes of the model, 'surgery' might profitably be considered a random effect.